# Different text style in word fields

Tags: ms-word

I have word document with bookmarks. There are some cross-references to this bookmarks values. All cross-reference are in text and has Arial 10 style.
For example, i have bookmark with "**Test text**", and cross-ref to this bookmark. But then i update fields word **Test** is normal Arial 10, but word **text** become Times New Roman 9 (first word save style of the text, which around my field, but second word become another (maybe standart for field) style).

I think, it's related to my Field Code - `{ REF BookmarkName \h \* MERGEFORMAT }`

How to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Delete the \\* MERGEFORMAT switch. If that doesn't achieve the desired result, replace it with a \\* CHARFORMAT switch and format the 'R' in 'REF' with the desired format.

Comment: Thank you very much! Second solution helped me! You can write it as answer and i will mark it